# Can not replace a special combination of characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arabic, farsi

I want to remove all `&zwj;` which have character "ا" after from a paragraph. I use the following method but console says that this combination is not found. Please consider that this is Persian word and the character "ا" is instantly after `&zwj;` as the characters are written **Right to Left** an the tail before character "ا" proves that they are connected together.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var htm=$("div").html();
   var shouldRemove="&zwj;ا";
   if (htm.includes(shouldRemove)){
       console.log('found');
   }
   else{
       console.log('not found');
   }
})
```

```css
body{font-size:26pt}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>&zwj;احترام</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching the entity `&zwj;` inside the HTML, search the character itself ([code point +U200D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner))  in the *text* value of the `div` node (not its HTML):

```js
console.log("Found?", $("div").text().includes("\u200Dا"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>&zwj;احترام</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this would be to convert the `&zwj;ا` into text, using the method below, and getting the text of the `div` instead of its html, then comparing the two texts:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   // get the text
   var div_txt = $("div").text();
   var shouldRemove = "&zwj;ا";
   // put it as html in a span, then get it as text
   var rem_txt = $("<span>").html(shouldRemove).text();
   if (div_txt.includes(rem_txt)) {
       console.log('found');
   } else {
       console.log('not found');
   }
})
```

```css
body {
    font-size:26pt
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>&zwj;احترام</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when reading an HTML entity from the DOM, the entity gets parsed, so the character sequence `&zwj;` turns into the single character ZERO WIDTH JOINER.

Your approach would work if you were to run JavaScript on the command line:

```
$ node
> s = '<div>&zwj;احترام</div>'
'<div>&zwj;احترام</div>'
> s.includes("&zwj;ا")
true
```

Even in a browser, if you use the JavaScript console directly, things work fine as you expected them to:

[image: screen capture of JS console in browser]

So what's different about reading from the DOM (in your case, with jQuery)? To see what is happening, let's check the actual characters within the string:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var htm=$("div").text();
   console.log(Array.from(htm));
   console.log(Array.from("&zwj;ا"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>&zwj;احترام</div>
```

This gives:

[image: Another cap]

Aha, so jQuery is parsing the HTML entity! Because of this, the text you want to search for should have the *JavaScript* zwj, not the HTML one. Specify it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var htm=$("div").html();
   var shouldRemove="\u{200d}ا";
   if (htm.includes(shouldRemove)){
       console.log('found');
   }
   else{
       console.log('not found');
   }
})
```

```css
body{font-size:26pt}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>&zwj;احترام</div>
```

Now it outputs `true`.

So all is well with RTL (text direction)! Turns out it's all just a matter of when HTML entities get parsed. :)

Comment: minor addition: it's not about jQuery. `document.querySelector('div').innerText` also returns entity already converted to string

Comment: Thank you yes you are absolutely right. I didn't _mean_ to blame jQuery but it sure did read that way. Edited the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you console log your htm variable it will o/p as: ‍احترام, so that's why when you try to search it with "‍ا", it outputs as 'not found'. Please try the below approach :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var htm=$("div").html();
   var shouldRemove="ا";
   if (htm.includes(shouldRemove)){
       console.log('found');
   }
   else{
       console.log('not found');
   }
})
```

```css
body{font-size:26pt}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>&zwj;احترام</div>
```